# Why does the length of a vowel before verb endings change?

Tags: classical-latin, verbs, conjugation, vowel-quantity

I'm learning Latin and I see that the stem I am supposed to add things onto keeps changing from long to short and back again. For example, take teneō, tenēre, tenuī, tentum.

As I see the present active first person singular is teneō, I might expect the e to always be short. However, I go to the second person singular and see tenēs. The third person singular is tenet. There is no pattern that I can see, as far as I'm aware. How do I know if the stem vowel of a verb will be short of long in a conjugation (not just present active)?

Comment: Welcome to the site! See this [similar older question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4334/79). Is it the same as yours?

Comment: Yes, it is basically the same. I didn't find that question in my (very quick) search. However, I like Draconis' answer better - I can understand it easily.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most people just memorize it. There are only four patterns to learn—all first-conjugation verbs will go *-ō -ās -at -āmus -ātis -ant*, for example—so this tends to be enough.

From a historical-linguistics perspective, though, we know that the vowels in the first, second, and fourth declensions were originally all long. But sound changes in the history of Latin sometimes shortened them: before another vowel (*habĕō*, *audĭō*) and before certain coda consonants (*amăt*, *amănt*).

So if you want to know the general rule, the stem vowel in the first, second, and fourth conjugations is always long unless:

- It comes before another vowel
- It comes before a final *r*, *m*, or *t*
- It comes before *nt* anywhere

The stem vowel in the third conjugation, on the other hand, is always short, unless it comes before *ns* or *nf* (which lengthen preceding vowels).

Comment: I think *nd* works like *nt*. (I wonder if this is a duplicate of the question and answer I linked to. Very similar at least.)